# Plot multiple rows of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like:

```
A    B    C    D
1    2    3    4
5    6    7    8
9    10   11   12
```

And I need to plot all three rows and not columns. I know I can use iloc if I want a specific row but looking for something that could plot all rows together:

```
df.iloc[0]
```

I have also tried:

```
df.plot()
```

which plots columns A,B,... instead of rows.

**NOTE:** Number of rows is variable for different dataframes and could be up to 200 so I am not interested in setting colors or stuff like that

Comment: do you need df.T.plot()?

Comment: @Vaishali That did the job, please post it as an answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can transpose the dataframe and then plot to plot the rows

```
df.T.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: @Vaishali- Is there away to do this without transposing the data? Because, if the dataframe is huge then transposing takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

So, you're plotting columns of data vs rows? Sounds like you need to transpose your dataframe. Use `df.T.plot()`

Comment: Data should always be structured with observations as rows, and categories as columns. I encourage you to read about "Tidy Data" to make your life MUCH easier down the road http://www.jeannicholashould.com/tidy-data-in-python.html